# RestSharp XML response to Object

Tags: c#, restsharp, asp.net-core-6.0

I am receiving the following XML response from a 3rd party API (which I cannot change):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <KervPingResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ActionCode>0</ActionCode>
            <ActionCodeDesc>Success</ActionCodeDesc>
        </KervPingResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want to convert whatever is in the "Body" to a C# class (or classes).

I have this generic code to make the call and return the response but I cannot get it to work. (I have temporarily fixed it to call the "Ping" method):

```
private async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(string action, object bodyData) where T : new()
{
    var reqData = "<Ping xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"></Ping>";

    var xml = string.Format("<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body>{0}</s:Body></s:Envelope>", reqData);

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Method = Method.Post;
    request.AddHeader("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/" + action + "\"");

    var xSig = GenerateXSig(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyData, Formatting.None));
    request.AddHeader("X-Signature", xSig);

    request.AddBody(xml, "text/xml");

    RestResponse<T> response = await _client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request);

    return response.Data;
}
```

The content of Response.Content is correct (as above) but I can't work out how to translate that into an Object. I have defined this, but do I need / have to define the "Envelope" and "Body" elements too?

```
[XmlRoot("KervPingResponse")]
public class KervPingResponse
{
    [XmlElement("ActionCode")]
    public int ActionCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ActionCodeDesc")]
    public string ActionCodeDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something in RestSharp (the latest version "107") to do it?

Even though the "Content" property is correct, I do see an error:

```
<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected.
```

Comment: Well, your response is wrapped in the `Envelope` and `Body` tags, which aren't part of your deserialization model. That's why it fails. You can try setting the root element to `KervPingResponse`.

Comment: You might get it to work with an explicit root and the Xml serializer package (the old one). https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#xml